# Cannot read property 'pkg' of null

Tags: ember.js, bower

I'm using Ember to compile a github project [here](https://github.com/szimek/webrtc-translate). I have Bower and npm installed as required. When I try to run `ember build` in the Node.js command prompt in the project directory I get the following:

```
(node:11980) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:11980) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
version: 0.0.44
Cannot read property 'pkg' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of null
    at Function.Addon.resolvePath (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:251:18)
    at Function.Addon.lookup (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:266:22)
    at C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:153:34
    at visit (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\utilities\DAG.js:23:3)
    at DAG.topsort (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\utilities\DAG.js:82:7)
    at Project.initializeAddons (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:151:9)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:176:10)
    at module.exports (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\cli\lookup-command.js:52:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:31:26)
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\project\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:470:16)
```

Comment: have you already run `bower install` and `npm install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the installation steps, you should be able to run the app:

> ### Installation
>
> - `git clone <repository-url>` this repository
> - change into the new directory
> - `npm install`
> - `bower install`

I tried it and it worked for me.

Note that the app uses an old Ember CLI version and is incompatible with Node 7.

Comment: sorry, the issue is with the continuous branch (https://github.com/szimek/webrtc-translate/tree/continuous). The main branch is fine.

Comment: That branch is really old. Do you even have a confirmation that it should work?